# Representação do auto-relacionamento muitos para muitos

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, entidade-relacionamento

Estou criando um Modelo Entidade-Relacionamento em que um Estudante pode ter muitos Estudantes, caracterizando portanto o auto-relacionamento de muitos para muitos.

Entretanto, estou com a dúvida de como implementar esse auto-relacionamento no momento de criação do banco. Devo criar a tabela Estudante e uma segunda tabela possuindo duas chaves de Estudante?

Caso ajude, estou fazendo este relacionamento para identificar quais amigos um Estudante adicionou dentro do sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, a forma de representar um relacionamento muitos-para-muitos é quebra-la em uma tabela intermediaria. Por exemplo em MySQL faríamos:

```
create table a(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  text varchar(60)
);

create table b(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  text varchar(60)
);
```

Agora o relacionamento das tabelas

```
create table a_b(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  a_id int,
  b_id int
  FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b(id)
);
```

Comment: Isso vale também para auto-relacionamentos? Estou ciente que de fato relacionamentos de cardinalidade M-N geram uma terceira tabela, mas no caso de uma entidade somente se relacionar com ela mesma eu não consigo visualizar a existência de três tabelas.

Comment: Entendi. Acho que compreendi errado seu problema. Nesse caso você pode simplesmente colocar uma chave apontando para ela mesmo. Não tem problema em fazer isso. Muito utilizando para criar categorias que tem subcategorias ou então quando querem criar a estrutura de um menu com submenus no banco de dados.